# Questions about PhysicsOverflow

Tags: discussion

I recently discovered https://www.physicsoverflow.org. I read some posts here on meta but none of them answered my questions.

- I understand that it is not a SE site, but isn't it the same for [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/)? Why can I find MO on the list of sites of SE, but not PO?
- They do seem to have an "import from PSE" sections. Is it encouraged from (or at least ok for) the SE community to have some link between the two sites?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6196/2451

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is Physics Overflow and how is it linked to Physics.SE?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6196/)

Comment: No, I read the answers but I didn't found what I was looking for. @Chris 's answer clarified what I needed to know.

Comment: Also related: [How did mathematics end up with two Stack Exchange sites, while Physics only got one?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9822)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Math Overflow was once not an SE site, but joined the SE network at some point. Physics Overflow is not and has never been associated with Stack Exchange.

Any import function is one-way and has nothing to do with Stack Exchange. Since all the content here is licensed under a creative commons share-alike license, Physics Overflow is free to copy content from here onto their own site without asking permission, so long as they follow the requirements of the license.

Comment: ... and since we're talking about licenses, and whether it's OK with PSE, then it bears mentioning that PO was, for several years, in unarguable violation of the CC BY-SA 3.0 license (specifically, the endorsement aspect of §4.c), and whether they have fixed it or not is questionable at best. For other reactions on the subject, see e.g. [this meta.MO thread](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/2025).